# Sed Search And Replace Question

Tags: regex, sed

What I can do if I want the "sed" to give me this ID as final result: b7f6fe86

The input might be `http://www.uploading.com/files/b76f5e86/hcadssoto720.part1.rar`
OR `http://uploading.com/files/b76f5e86/hcadssoto720.part1.rar` and I want the output to give the ID of this link.

For instance

```
echo http://uploading.com/files/b76f5e86/hcadssoto720.part1.rar | sed 's/SOMETHING/SOMETHING/g"
```

OUTPUT: b7f6fe86

```
echo http://www.uploading.com/files/b76f5e86/hcadssoto720.part1.rar | sed 's/SOMETHING/SOMETHING/g"
```

OUTPUT: b7f6fe86

I hope to get the help of regular expression experts.
Cheers

Answer (score 3):

```
cut -d'/' -f5
```

Should do it afaik.

Comment: This will only work if the thing you are after is after the 4th slash. Is it?

Comment: @user, it is in both the examples.

Comment: Yes, which was exactly what the OP described he wanted (at least: that's where it is located). A whole lot more readable then something like `grep -P -o  '(?<=files\/)[a-z0-9]+'`, and IMHO, readability is a great plus :)

Answer (score 1):

try:

`echo "http://uploading.com/files/b76f5e86/hcadssoto720.part1.rar" | sed 's|\([^/]*/\)\{4\}\([0-9a-f]*\).*|\2|'`

Note that the '/' character is replaced by the '|' character to simplify the appearance of "leaning toothpick syndrome".

Bah - can't make some '*' appear properly - ah - got it.